# How does one structure multiple related entities in React & Flux/Redux/Alt?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux, alt

Architecture question that I think applies to any state container. I'm using Alt now, have used Redux in the past, but in general...

Say I have Blog Posts, Users, and Comments.  In the database, I store this normalized as a Blog Posts table, Users table, and Comments table, but Blog Posts and Users can both have Comments associated via a join table.

On the React side, I make actions and reducers for all three entities as well, BlogPostActions, BlogPostReducer, etc.  Now, in order to serve a page that has BlogPosts and Comments, I need to fetch BlogPosts, then fetch comments using something like `redux-thunk`.

Now my issue is - if I have a page that displays BlogPosts and Users and they both have comments, how do I structure the Comments Reducer/Store?  My naive solution is usually to set a List of Comments - the result from the action dispatch.  This turns into an infinite loop - BlogPosts asks for Comments, Users asks for comments, whichever wins triggers props to change and thus triggers rerenders, which kicks the whole thing off all over again.

I can think of a couple solutions - I'm tempted to slice Comments into BlogComments and UserComments although the redux docs advise against this.  I'd rather keep only one Comments store and in the Action dispatch only fetch Comments that I know I haven't already fetched.  Eventually, my single Comments store will have all the UserComments and BlogComments I need and will stop triggering rerenders.  My only problem with this is in Alt, I don't seem to have access to state in my Action, but I remember having this in Redux.

Which of these is more idiomatic Flux/Redux/Alt-y?

Comment: Hi @lucas, for 'redux' I would refer you to this page [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape#normalizing-state-shape)

Comment: Thanks @SDP190 - I've seen that page before, but it's good to have a refresher. Some background - I used ember.js before react and I'm used to ember-data managing models as kind of an ORM on top of REST.  Ideally I want redux to be something like that too, where I can fetch objects & their dependencies incrementally into the store on demand until I've got all of them, and ideally the store knows whether or not it needs to remote, caching as it goes (invalidation becomes the next question, but...)